# Data importing with special characters in BCP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, bcp

I am trying to import the data from csv source file , and my source file data contains special characters, I am using below CMD, it is not working for me,

```
'bcp ' + db_name() + '.dbo.' + @sTableName + ' in ' + @sInputFile + ' -S ' 
+ @@SERVERNAME + ' -m 10000 -T -t "|" -w -E -e '+@sInputFileBCPLog
```

and if i use below command data is loading but data is mismatching due to  special characters,

```
'bcp ' + db_name() + '.dbo.' + @sTableName + ' in ' + @sInputFile + ' -S ' +
@@SERVERNAME + ' -m 10000 -T -t "|" -c -E -e '+@sInputFileBCPLog
```

please find below input and output , which output is loading for me ,

in source file one column value like below ,
China (People’s Republic of)

in output table it is loading  like below ,
China (PeopleÆs Republic of)

Comment: This likely happens because your source file contains `’` encoded with the byte `0x92`, which is the code point it has in the Windows-1252 encoding, but it ends up being interpreted in code page 437, where `0x92` is the code point for `Æ`. Try adding `-C ACP` to your options, which makes `bcp` use Windows-1252.

Comment: Hi Jeroen Mostert ,
I have used -C ACP, 
i am getting below error ,
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unable to open BCP error-file

Comment: That's an entirely different error and has nothing to do with the code page option. Did you tack it on after `-e`, by any chance? `-e` is followed by the path to the error log. Use `-c -C ACP -E -e ...`.

Comment: I used like above same error i  am getting

Comment: Then you'll need to verify that `@sInputFileBCPLog` points to a valid file name and is accessible.

Comment: thanks , its working fine for me

Comment: by using BCP , how many number of columns can be import to SQL ?